# Getting Mouse Click Coordinates

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a Project in c# and need to get Mouse Click Coordinates in the textbox. Clicking can be made outside the Screen. I have found a code in the internet but can't make the coordinates bring out in the textbox. Here is the code.. I was trying to write "hookStruct.pt.x" in HookCallBack but it didn't work as well. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

```
namespace Mouse_Hook
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
            LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;

        private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 &&
            MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {

                MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
                Console.WriteLine(hookStruct.pt.x + ", " + hookStruct.pt.y); 
                Console.Read();
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public POINT pt;
            public uint mouseData;
            public uint flags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        private enum MouseMessages
        {
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
            WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
            WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
            WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
            WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
            Application.Run();
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What really `didn't work well`? Except the weird `Application.Run` inside the form load and `Console` calls from inside a WF application.

Comment: I want to set "textbox1.Text = hookStruct.pt.x"  instead of Console.Writeline but there is no textbox1, just TextBox class

Comment: Finding a TextBox back from a *static* method is usually a fail whale.  You need a reference, you don't have one.  A very simple workaround is to just not make it static but an instance member of whatever Window or Form that contains the textbox.  Best to learn OOP before trying to hack hooks.

Comment: :D and donn't want to hack. I just need coordinates of Mouse Click

Comment: You say that "HookCallback" mustn't be static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the best for your needs would be to put the hook functionality inside a static (global) class and expose a static event. In your case, the form will subscribe on that event when opened (and should unsubscribe when closed). Something like this

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    public static class MouseHook
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
                    LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

        private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public POINT pt;
            public uint mouseData;
            public uint flags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        private enum MouseMessages
        {
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
            WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
            WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
            WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
            WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
        }

        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

        public static void Register()
        {
            if (_hookID != IntPtr.Zero) return;
            _hookID = SetHook(HookCallback);
        }

        public static void Unregister()
        {
            if (_hookID == IntPtr.Zero) return;
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
            _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {
                var handler = LButtonDown;
                if (handler != null) handler(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        public static event EventHandler LButtonDown;
    }
    // Test
    class TestForm : Form
    {
        Label label;
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            Controls.Add(label = new Label());
            MouseHook.LButtonDown += OnHookLButtonDown;
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }
        protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            MouseHook.LButtonDown -= OnHookLButtonDown;
        }
        private void OnHookLButtonDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var pt = Control.MousePosition;
            label.Text = "{" + pt.X + ", " + pt.Y + "}";
        }
    }
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            MouseHook.Register();
            try { Application.Run(new TestForm()); }
            finally { MouseHook.Unregister(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that this is just an example. A production code would extract the information from the hook parameters and expose a global events similar to the standard `MoseMove`, `MouseDown` etc.